# adding Options like size and color in wishlist sidebar magento2

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.1.2.I am having issue to get the wishlist product attributes like color,size in wishlist sidebar.

Here is the code which get the price name etc but unable to get the attributes like size and color

```
protected function getItemData(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem) {
        $product = $wishlistItem->getProduct();        
        return [
            'image' => $this->getImageData($product),
            'product_url' => $this->wishlistHelper->getProductUrl($wishlistItem),
            'product_name' => $product->getName(),
            'product_color' => 'Blue',
            'product_size' => 'L',
            'product_price' => $this->block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $product,
                'wishlist_configured_price',
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                ['item' => $wishlistItem]
            ),
            'product_is_saleable_and_visible' => $product->isSaleable() && $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_has_required_options' => $product->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($product),
            'add_to_cart_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getAddToCartParams($wishlistItem, true),
            'delete_item_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getRemoveParams($wishlistItem, true),
        ];
    }
```

THanks

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to hack the core for that. You need to [create a plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) that modifies the result of this method. But since this method is protected you will not be able to just hook into that. You can hook into `getSectionData` which is `public`.

Another gotcha is that the wishlist items are stored in local storage by the browser. So when testing, after you cleared the Magento cache, you will also have to clear the local storage of your site in the browser and log in again and then add another item to your wishlist.

When you created a module you can then add these files:

app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData;

class Wishlist
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $wishlistHelper;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function afterGetSectionData(
        \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $collection = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();
        $collection->clear()->setPageSize(count($result['items']))->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at');

        foreach($result['items'] as &$item) {
            foreach ($collection as $wishlistItem) {
                $product = $wishlistItem->getProduct();
                if ($item['product_url'] == $product->getProductUrl()) {
                    $item['product_color'] = $product->getAttributeText('color');
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Wishlist_CustomerData_Wishlist" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in a file that overwrites app/code/Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/sidebar.phtml

You can do something like

```
<span data-bind="visible: product_color, text: product_color"></span>
```

inside the

```
<li class="product-item">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of showing product attribute in wishlist sidebar,

**First Need to Remove all the wishlist items ,clear cache and add a new product to wishlist.**

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Yourtheme_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Wishlist" />
       </sequence>
     </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="Yourtheme\yourmodule\CustomerData\Wishlist" />
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/CustomerData/Wishlist.php

```
namespace YourTheme\YourModule\CustomerData;

/**
* Wishlist section
*/
class Wishlist extends \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist
{

/**
 * Get wishlist items
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getWishlistItems()
{
    $this->view->loadLayout();

    $collection = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();
    $collection->clear()->setPageSize(self::SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER)
        ->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at');

    $items = [];
    foreach ($collection as $wishlistItem) {
        $items[] = $this->getProductItemData($wishlistItem);
    }
    return $items;
}

  /**
 * Retrieve wishlist item data
 *
 * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem
 * @return array
 */
protected function getProductItemData(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem)
{
    $product = $wishlistItem->getProduct();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $model = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface');

    $custpomProductAttribute = $product->getYourAttribute();

    return [
        'image' => $this->getImageData($model->getFinalProduct($wishlistItem)),
        'product_sku' => $product->getSku(),
        'product_id' => $product->getId(),
        'product_url' => $this->wishlistHelper->getProductUrl($wishlistItem),
        'product_name' => $product->getName(),
        'product_price' => $this->block->getProductPriceHtml(
            $product,
            'wishlist_configured_price',
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
            ['item' => $wishlistItem]
        ),
        'product_is_saleable_and_visible' => $product->isSaleable() &&    
      $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
        'product_has_required_options' => $product->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($product),
        'add_to_cart_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getAddToCartParams($wishlistItem),
        'delete_item_params' => $this->wishlistHelper->getRemoveParams($wishlistItem),
        'your_attribute' => $custpomProductAttribute,
    ];
}
```

Comment: And you can get that attribute using ko in sidebar.phtm in wishlist modulel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Victor S.
Tried first method, to override the class via preferences, but no lucky, after an hour trying to compile and recompile dependency injection, found your answer and created a module with the plugin, magically works. Magento 2.2.7.

Thanks